# Generating a root index file during a node package build

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript

At the moment, I have a package that generates the following:

```
package_name
-- README.md
-- package.json
---- /dist
---- /node_modules
```

Unfortunately, a consumer cannot use this package as it stands now since there is no `index.js` in the root. I need to add one so that the package builds to:

```
package_name
-- README.md
-- package.json
-- index.js      // need to generate this file
---- /dist
---- /node_modules
```

Where the `./index.js` is exporting the exports of `./dist/index.js`.

`./dist` is structured as:

```
index.js
dir1
-- files
dir2
-- files
```

Context:

Unfortunately the consumer is a custom JS runtime that only looks for `index.js` within the root or within `/src`. I don't want to use `/src` as tsc will pollute the workspace with js files. That's why i'd like to redirect the output to `dist` and then have a root level index to read exports from it.

Answer (score 0):

u need use something like this

https://github.com/bluelovers/ws-string/blob/master/packages/runes2/package.json#L28

```json
  "exports": {
    ".": {
      "types": "./dist/index.d.ts",
      "require": "./dist/index.cjs",
      "import": "./dist/index.esm.mjs"
    },
    "./index": {
      "types": "./dist/index.d.ts",
      "require": "./dist/index.cjs",
      "import": "./dist/index.esm.mjs"
    },
    "./package.json": "./package.json",
    "./src/*": "./src/*"
  },
```